# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: php, laravel-4, gmail, smtpclient

I've configured to gmail SMTP server to send email. Account less secure app turned ON, also [Recapture](http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) thing enabled. Here is the `mail.php` configuration.

This code working fine on hostgator server. But we have another server, mails are not sending from that server. What should I do now?

**Error image**

http://screencast.com/t/BSCurEEubPJV

```
return array(    
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => array('address' => 'xxx@gmail.com', 'name' => 'xxxxTeam'),
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'xx@123',    
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same issue. Finally found that my server IP address was blacklisted. 
Please check your IP address using this link.

Link : https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

If it is blacklisted, send re-list request via they provide links. That's it

Thank you

Comment: sorry but i could not get from where i can send re-list request